# Half Modal Open Button Works

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Half of my button works. i have found that the cause is the modal location covers the right half of my button when the modal is open. I cannot seem to get the full button to work because of this. just the left half of my button is clickable.

the following [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdYzI.png) shows how the modal covers the right half of the button.

the modal works perfectly if i click on the left half of the button. but the right half is the problem.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#departmentModal">Add/Update Departments</button>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="departmentModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Department PopUp</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <table id="tblAddDepartment">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblBusinessUnitCode" runat="server" Text="Business Unit Code: " /></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusinessUnitCode" runat="server" MaxLength="1" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDepartmentCode" runat="server" Text="Department Code: " /></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartmentCode" runat="server" MaxLength="4" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="Business Unit - Department Code: " /></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" onserverclick="btnSubmitDepartment_Click" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: How do i get the full button working not just half

Comment: So when you click the button, the modal pops up and covers the right half of the button. But you want to be able to see the full button still? Why are you clicking the button after the modal is already open?

Comment: even when the modal isn't visible or open its 'covering' the right half of the button making it not work. i don't care if i see the button while the modal is visible, i just want the button to fully work not just half of it.

Comment: Ahhh, I understand now. Have you tried setting the modal class's CSS property `display` to none?

Comment: i have not!! ill give that a shot!!!

Comment: i guess where would i set that property?

Comment: If you were the one who wrote the class 'modal' I would put it in there. Otherwise you could make a new class called 'hide' or something and all that to your modal element. Also remember that when the button is pressed you need to set the display property to something other than none using javascript.